# Adobe edge issue IE Animation not load undefined stage error

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, adobe, adobe-edge

We are having the following Issue with edge animate published banner.

TypeError: Unable to get property 'stage' of undefined or null reference\n   at init (animate.adobe.com/runtime/5.0.1/edge.5.0.1.min.jTypeError: Unable to get property 'stage' of undefined or null reference\n   at init (animate.adobe.com/runtime/5.0.1/edge.5.0.1.min.j

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'stage' of undefined or null reference
File: edge.5.0.1.min.js, Line: 133, Column: 135

The errors it only occurs at IE 11 so the animation does not load.

Here is the hosted banner
http://dev.two-uk.com/ishares/advertising/core_tool/300x250/

Is a very simple animation the only changes done is on the document ready function inserted an adserver requirements. However for now is commented for testing purposes

```
//Edge binding end
/*Symbol.bindElementAction(compId,symbolName,"document","compositionReady",function(sym,e) {
  function initEB(){if(!EB.isInitialized()){EB.addEventListener(EBG.EventName.EB_INITIALIZED,startAd );}else{startAd();}}
  function startAd(){sym.$("windowDisclaimer").hide();sym.play();}
  initEB();
});*/
Symbol.bindElementAction(compId,symbolName,"document","compositionReady",function(sym,e){
  console.log("compositionReady");
  sym.play();
});
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

In your main .html file, call the 'EBLoader.js' script file before the 'edge.x.x.x.min.js' file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://secure-ds.serving-sys.com/BurstingScript/EBLoader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://animate.adobe.com/runtime/6.0.0/edge.6.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

Have also read that for some people, removing "use strict" from the 5th line of the non-published 'file_edge.js' file solved this issue for them though, didn't find this helped me:

```
"use strict";
```